Assessing first cousin once removed relationship based on 476cM shared match
My mother's sister is my maternal aunt.
Therefore, her son should be my first cousin.
I match his daughter's DNA at 476cM.  She should be my first cousin once removed.
When I look at the chart the 476 CM shows me that she is A half first cousin am I reading it right I also read when it shows a half first cousin there are dark secrets and something's not right My mother recently died and before she died she told me that My father wasn't my father but she wouldn't tell me who was But she had dementia but I always thought he wasn't is it possible my mother could have slept with his father My cousin's daughter's ancestry numbers are below:
1st–2nd Cousin
Shared DNA: 
476 cM across 27 segments
1st cousin 1x removed
7% shared DNA: 476 cM across 27 segments


It seems to me that the Shared cM value of 476cM indicates that a first cousin once removed relationship between you and your mouther's sister's daughter has an 89% probability of being correct.
You can remain open to other theories but I think the DNA evidence is that they are far less likely.

Hi thank you for reply

Yes you're correct
Hi thank you for the reply when I first got an email saying I was related to a certain girl that she was my first slash second cousin the second part I don't understand When I look up our match of 476 CM states that she is a half first cousin her father which I know just recently after 40 years obviously would be my first half cousin I always assume he was my full cousin but she was the first match showing on ancestry his daughter I'm getting that down at this point Thank you you are the only person that made that clear I appreciate it

So what I understand now her father my first half cousin We only share one grandparent so my mother and my aunt had to have different fathers which would be The first time our family knew that

Hi thank you for the reply when I first got an email saying I was related to a certain girl that she was my first slash second cousin the second part I don't understand When I look up our match of 476 CM states that she is a half first cousin her father which I know just recently after 40 years obviously would be my first half cousin I always assume he was my full cousin but she was the first match showing on ancestry his daughter I'm getting that down at this point the whole reason why I posted this before my mother died she told me who I thought was my real father wasn't but she would not tell me who was this was a year ago then 6 months later I get an email saying I have a match that was a half cousin which was my cousin's daughter which ancestry tells me that she and her father is half first cousins regardless of the first removed So we only share one grand parent so that means my mother my aunt have different fathers

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
